# PGP Encryption & PGP Decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle, pgp

I'm having trouble decrypting files using the BouncyCastle OpenPGP API. I followed this post: http://rafayal.blogspot.com/2009/06/pgp-decryption-with-c.html to decrypt files. However, I am getting an error that states that the KeyID cannot be null whenever I instantiate the PGPDecrypt object.

```
PGPDecrypt test = new PGPDecrypt(@"C:\test\somefile.zip",
                                             @"C:\GnuPG\secring.gpg",
                                             "password",
                                             @"C:\test\test",
                                             @"C:\GnuPG\pubring.asc",
                                             666362230);
            FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\test\somefile.zip", FileMode.Open);
            test.decrypt(fs,@"C:\test\test");
```

I'm creating the key using Kleopatra on the Gpg4Win tool set.

Within the PGPDecrypt class, when the PGPKeys object is being instantiate (specifically the PgpPublicKey object) , I am getting the error that states that the KeyID cannot be null. Can some body please help.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Just a quick comment that this kind of thing is normally asked and aswered on the dev-crypto mailinglist of bouncy castle.